# Does there exist a faithful representation of degree $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$ where field is real or complex. Does there exist a faithful $FG$-module of dimension $n$ (in other words a representation of degree $n$) other than the regular $FG$- module (or representation)?

I think it should be no, as every such representation will be isomorphic to regular one.

Comment: I would think it's more difficult to come up with examples of non-trivial groups such that the regular representation would be the only faithful rep of dimension $n$. Over $\Bbb{R}$ I think $C_3$ is one. Over $\Bbb{C}$ I can't think of any.

Comment: It's quite false that any such representation is isomorphic to the regular representation. For example, if $G = C_p$ is cyclic of order a prime $p$ then every nontrivial representation is faithful. The regular representation contains every irreducible exactly once and there are many other representations of dimension $p$ containing the irreducibles with different multiplicities.

Comment: Or a nonabelian example: Both nonabelian groups of order 8 ($D_{2\cdot 4}$ and $Q_8$) have a nontrivial faithful representation of degree 2, and you can take the direct sum of 4 copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can exist. For instance, consider the Klein four group: the regular rep decomposes as a direct sum of all four 1D irreps, but we can construct another faithful 4D rep by direct summing any four 1D reps at least two of which are distinct nontrivial. Indeed, you can take the direct sum of two distinct nontrivial permutation 2D reps.